# Why cant I pass the event?

Tags: javascript, function, event-listener

Why cant I pass the event to the ckeckKey function?

```
var restElement = document.getElementById('div');

function SpelKontroll() {
window.addEventListener('keydown', checkKey(event));
}
function checkKey(event) {
switch(event.keyCode) {
  case 37: // left
      console.log("hello");
      break;
    }         
}
```

If someone knows I would be very Thankfull!

Comment: Does the `console` give any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', checkKey);
```

The second parameter of `window.addEventListener` must be a function, while you're using a call.

Answer (score 0):

Worsk for me - remove param from function definition.

http://jsfiddle.net/NSDtA/

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', checkKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do it like this:

```
function SpelKontroll() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { checkKey(e) });
}
```

This way it will work.